# Android: Expandable list not expanded on a screen fully

Tags: android, listview

[image: This is my App screen on the top there is an expandable listview, and underneath there are buttons having images,]

This is my App screen on the top there is an expandable listview, and underneath there are buttons having images,

[image: now the problem is the expandable listview expands on specific area not expand itself to show all items as displayed in snap,]

now the problem is the expandable listview expands on specific area not expand itself to show all items as displayed in snap,

I need that, when user click on parent item it expands itself with child items on the front of all button so that the buttons are hidden behind the listview, or when user scrolling the buttons the button goes behind the listview...
just like admob ad that is displayed on the front of every thing here is the snaps of that also

[image: i want to show listview like this, as admob banner]
i want to show listview like this, as admob banner

here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:background="@drawable/background2">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ExpandableListView>







    <Button

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/anaheim"

        android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
        android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boston"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"
        android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
        android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buffalo"
        android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
        android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do not put scrollable containter(ExpandableListView) into another scrollable containter(ScrollView)

Comment: i put it outside the scroll view also, but then it will show only the listview items not the button,

Comment: put buttons first into relativelayout (at the **bottom** of it) then put expandablelistview **above** them

Comment: kindly please make your answer by editing my xml code, Thanks its more informative for me then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:background="@drawable/background2">


<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


<Button

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/button31"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/anaheim"

    android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/boston"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"
    android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buffalo"
    android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks to @selvin